# No save option for layer in ArcGIS Online

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, save

I am very new to ArcGIS Online. I created a new layer in a map, but there is nor save as button in menu

I tried to create a layer in my map using Map Notes, but after finishing I noticed there is no "save" option either for the layer, nor for the project.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop so did you create your layer in ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Online?  Please provide a more detailed description of your workflow.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS online. I created a new layer in a map, but there is nor save as button in menu

Comment: Are you logged in to an ArcGIS account?

Comment: Unless you're using a configured Edit widget, all of your edits are saved automatically.